# Why am I not able to create an app OR port forward in ArgoCD?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I'm trying to setup ArgoCD to automatically deploy Kubernetes manifests from a remote repository.

Argocd is installed on my K3s cluster. The CLI is working... kind of. I can't do `argocd app create name` (with or without additional parameters) or it stalls in the terminal indefinitely... I'm not exactly sure what the word is for this, but the terminal never prompts me for another command. Note that if I do `argo app create --help` it does not stall-- it displays the help message.

Because of this, I want to use the UI to add an app to argo. This requires port forwarding to port 8080. I am trying to do this with the following command:

`kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443`

But it prints

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
```

With the cursor on the third line... This command *also* stalls indefinitely! I've waited for quite a while and nothing happens. Nothing else is running on port 8080 on any of the nodes.

Someone please give some guidance on how to proceed here? I am brand new to ArgoCD and Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

This was a silly misunderstanding on my part of how the `argocd port-forward` command works. When you run `kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443`, it sets up a proxy so that you can communicate with the argocd server through port 8080. When that program ends, the proxy closes-- so when you press `control+c`, thinking the command is "stuck", you are actually just closing the proxy you set up.

The solution is to run `kubectl port-forward svc/argocd-server -n argocd 8080:443`, open a new shell, and use the new shell to login and interact with ArgoCD.